# C++ VS Debug code, set your own debug flags

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I wonder if there is way to define your own debug flags in VS for C++.
For example the code below is only executed in debug mode. I want to have another piece of code that maybe prints `"Hello World"`that only prints at debug level 2. How do you define a level 2 debug flag in VS? is it via properties?

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
#endif
```

Comment: What is "debug level 2"?

Comment: Make your own, an appropriate name for the macro would be TRACE_LEVEL.  Or don't make your own, tracing and logging libraries are widely available.  Look at log4cpp for example.

Answer (score 4):

You use your own macros.

```
#ifdef DEBUG_LEVEL_2
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
#endif
```

or

```
#if defined (DEBUG_LEVEL) && DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
#endif
```

and then you either

```
#define DEBUG_LEVEL_2
```

or

```
#define DEBUG_LEVEL 2
```

manually, or define it in the "Preprocessor" tab in the project settings, or pass it to the compiler using the `/D`flag if you're compiling on the command line.